How to fill the area between a curve and a line
This is what I have for the curve and the line but I don't know how to fill the space between them
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8]
\draw[help lines, dashed] (0,0) grid (8,11);
\draw[thick] (0,6)--(8,6);
\draw[thick] (5,0)--(5,11);
\draw[red] (1.75,0) .. controls (4.8,12) .. (7,6);
\draw[blue] (1.5,0) -- (6.5,10);

\end{tikzpicture}


Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.
